# Add ternary operator instead condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add a ternary operator to this code.

```
 {suggestedTags.length > 0 && (
      <div className={classes.tagSuggestionWrapper}>
        {suggestedTags.map((tag) => {
          return (<div key={tag} 
                       className={classes.tagSuggestion} 
                       onClick={() => { selectTag(tag) }}>{tag}</div>
                       );            
        })}
      </div>
    )}
```

I'll explain why: I don't need to check > 0 manually because any length more than 0 will be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below uses ternary:

```
${suggestedTags.length > 0 ? (
      <div className={classes.tagSuggestionWrapper}>
        {suggestedTags.map((tag) => {
          return (<div key={tag} 
                       className={classes.tagSuggestion} 
                       onClick={() => { selectTag(tag) }}>{tag}</div>
                       );            
        })}
      </div>
    ) : ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
Boolean(suggestedTags.length) && (<yourElement/>)
```

I don't see the need for a ternary unless you have to render something if the length ends up being 0.